# Getting IO Exception Fault When Trying To Copy Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to create a SqliteManager Class to use Sqlite database. But when I am trying to copy database I am getting an IO Error. Here is my code :

```
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error(e.getMessage());

            }
```

I am trying to copy database here.

```
     private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = helperContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

This is my copyDatabase function. I am getting error `myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);` here.

```
11-23 10:38:23.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.Error
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at cf.android.dbsmpl.SqliteManager$DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(SqliteManager.java:291)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at cf.android.dbsmpl.SqliteManager.open(SqliteManager.java:60)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at cf.android.dbsmpl.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:31)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2335)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at cf.android.dbsmpl.DbsmplMainActivity.onCreate(DbsmplMainActivity.java:27)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-23 10:38:23.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the error log. When I debug this code, it shows that cause of this error is IOException. 
I am stuck and I hope you help me to figure this out where is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot these variables. 
DB_PATH :"/data/data/cf.android.dbsmpl/databases/";

Comment: There is no IOException here. You need to log it, and post it here. Question cannot be answered in its present form.

Comment: Do you have your original database stored in the assets folder in your android project? It will need to be there for the call to helperContext.getAssets().open to pick it up.

Comment: `Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception' you have caught IO Exception here, May be you are not getting IOException, just try `atch(Exception e) ` and print your stack trace

Comment: @EJP afo is catching the IOException and throwing an Error which he supplies with the IOException's message. Cutting down the information that he is getting from the original exception, so probably better not to do the catch and rethrow, just let the IOException propagate up.

Comment: @Pawan he is getting an IOException alright. The only way to get that Error handler to run is to catch the IOException. You are correct in that the full stack trace needs to be posted though.

Comment: @EJP as I mentioned when I debug code I looked up "e" variables cause it shows that is IOException fault. I changed `catch (Exception e)` instead of `catch (IOException e)` result was same.

Comment: So what was the (a) class (b) message and (c) stack trace of the original IOException? Without that information nobody can help you.

Comment: I tried to add screenshot but my rep is not enough. My class is SQliteManager. detailed error message : null . stacktrace is also null. By the way I tried the code on another emulator it worked fine. Is it about OS version ?

Comment: @afo You can delete the stacktrace of the Error to make room: it's of no interest. Or you can keep not posting the IOException, keep beating around the bush, and never get an answer. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.dinota.emc/databases/UFS-SG.db"); //change this to your original location

    String outFileName = "/data/data/com.dinota.emc/databases/" + "UFS-SG.db1"; //change this location as well
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[myInput.available()];

    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Try this way. This works without any issues..

Comment: what's the error you are getting? Is it different error or same one ?

Comment: I got same error. Btw I didn't change myInput source because my database is in assets folder. That is the only one difference.

Comment: check whether your InputStream is null or not ? If possible just try once the above method without any changes.

Comment: InputStream is not null. If it were probably i would get FileNotFound Exception. As I mentioned above the comment to EJP it works fine with Android OS 2.3.